# Including references in a tokenlist using expl3

Tags: hyperref, expl3, ref, token-lists

I am trying to create a document with math exercises, for each math exercise one or more hints are given that should be show in a later section.
From the inserted hints it should be possible to jump back to the matching question.
When I try to insert a `ref` to the question, latex gives me the error

```
! Argument of \@firstoftwo has an extra }
```

Each of the given hints are saved in a global token list and first rendered at the end of the document. This work decently, but I would like to include an link from the hint back to the exercise. I have highlighted my attempted solution with TODO in the code.

The code is provided at the end of this post and the rendered output is shown here:

[image: Rendered output]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expl3}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\tl_new:N \g_allgivenhints_tl
\tl_new:N \l_temp_tl

\newcounter{exercise} 

% Define an environment for numbered exercises.
\NewDocumentEnvironment{exercise}{O{}+b}{
% Begin exercise
\refstepcounter{exercise}
\noindent
Exercise~\theexercise\par
\label{exercise\theexercise}
\noindent #2
}{
% End exercise
\medskip
}

% Define an environment for hints to exercises.
% All hints should be at the end of the document
% where the \showhints command is inserted.
\NewDocumentEnvironment{hint}{O{}+b}{%
\tl_gput_right:Nn \g_allgivenhints_tl { \par\noindent }
\tl_gput_right:Nx \g_allgivenhints_tl { Hint~for~exercise~\theexercise }
% TODO
% TODO
% TODO: The line below is what I think I want to do, but it fails ...
% TODO
% TODO
%\tl_gput_right:Nx \g_allgivenhints_tl { Hint~for~exercise~\theexercise \ref{exercise\theexercise{}} }
\tl_gput_right:Nn \g_allgivenhints_tl { \par\noindent }
\tl_gput_right:Nn \g_allgivenhints_tl { #2 }
\tl_gput_right:Nn \g_allgivenhints_tl { \medskip }
}{
% hint end
}

% Define a command that inserts all the given
% hints at that location.
\NewDocumentCommand{\showhints}{}{\tl_use:N \g_allgivenhints_tl}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\section{Exercises}
\label{secExercise}

\begin{exercise}
Question in exercise one.
\begin{hint}
Hint for exercise one.
\end{hint}
\end{exercise}


\begin{exercise}
Question in exercise two.
\begin{hint}
Hint for exercise two.
\end{hint}
\end{exercise}



\section{Hints}
Manual reference to exercise one \ref{exercise1}.

\noindent
Manual reference to exercise two \ref{exercise2}.
\medskip

\showhints


\end{document}
```

Comment: You want `\exp_not:N \ref`, I guess.

Comment: Thanks #egreg it now works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `\exp_not:N \ref`, to avoid untimely expansion.

However, I'd use a slightly different approach, with a sequence.

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage{xparse} % not needed with LaTeX 2020-10-01 or later
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newcounter{exercise} 

\ExplSyntaxOn

\seq_new:N \g_midtiby_hints_seq

% Define an environment for numbered exercises.
\NewDocumentEnvironment{exercise}{O{}}
 {
  % Begin exercise
  \par
  \addvspace{\medskipamount}
  \refstepcounter{exercise}\label{exercise\theexercise}
  \noindent
  Exercise~\theexercise\par\nobreak
  \noindent\ignorespaces
 }
 {
  % End exercise
  \par\addvspace{\medskipamount}
 }

% Define an environment for hints to exercises.
% All hints should be at the end of the document
% where the \showhints command is inserted.
\NewDocumentEnvironment{hint}{O{}+b}
 {
  \seq_gput_right:Nx \g_midtiby_hints_seq
   {
    \noindent Hint~for~exercise~\exp_not:N \ref{exercise\theexercise}
    \exp_not:n { \par\nobreak\noindent #2 }
   }
 }
 {
  % hint end
 }

% Define a command that inserts all the given
% hints at that location.
\NewDocumentCommand{\showhints}{}
 {
  \par\addvspace{\medskipamount}
  \seq_use:Nn \g_midtiby_hints_seq { \par\addvspace{\medskipamount} }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\begin{exercise}
This is easy.
\end{exercise}
\begin{hint}
No hint here.
\end{hint}

\begin{exercise}
This is easy again.
\end{exercise}
\begin{hint}
No hint here.
\end{hint}

\begin{exercise}
This is not easy.
\end{exercise}
\begin{hint}
A long hint here.
\end{hint}

\showhints

\end{document}
```

[image]